# Invalid volume specification when starting a docker from VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-2019

**Update**

Strangely enough, but if I replace base image with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim` everything works fine.
But it must be the same image [`tags:3.0.0-buster-slim, 3.0-buster-slim, 3.0.0, 3.0, latest`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet/)

---

**Update 2**

I have a question for MSFT:

> **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet - 3.0 - ec6c9791ce4a - 3 days ago - 346MB**
>   mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet - 3.0.0 - ec6c9791ce4a -3 days ago - 346MB
>   **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet - 3.0-buster-slim - 675139f95df1 - 3 days ago - 221MB**
>   mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet - 3.0.0-rc1-buster-slim - 15b700e0a20c - 10 days ago - 221MB

`3.0.0` and `3.0` are Windows containers. You little liars ;-)

---

**Update 3**

This is even crazier than I thought.

If I do `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0` from Windows 10 (under Parallels) I get image with hash **`ec6c9791ce4a`**.

BUT! If I run absolutely the same command in iOS, I end up with the image having hash **`675139f95df1`**.

*WTF is going on?!*

---

I try to start my project in a dockerized form and I get the error:

> error CTC1015: docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages'.

and

> error CTC1015: docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '...\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw'.

Error window points to `Container.targets` file which is located at `...\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.9.5\build\Container.targets`

It's weird that volume points to Xamarin as my solution has no related projects, and vs2017u5 is strange.

I use latest VS2019 version `16.3.1`

Here is `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./published .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "luscii.identity.service.dll"]
```

And here is publish profile:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>a6fc12f4-6fdb-4a1b-a769-ef609b5e18eb</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>published</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/same-docker-command-executed-on-different-os-yields-different-result-why/81898